# Переименовать конкретное Activity (Android Development)

Tags: android, eclipse

Как переименовать конкретное Activity в Action Bar (чтобы разные активити имели разные заголовки при просмотре в Graphical layout)

Comment: setTitle() пробовали вызывать в методе onCreate() Вашей активити?

Comment: Graphical layout это предпросмотр в eclipse?

Comment: Graphical layout это предварительный просмотр в eclipse текущего Activity,Вы правы)  Проблема в том , что меняя имя одного активити , изменяются имена всех активити(

Comment: Рекомендую перейти на Intellij Idea или Android Studio, т.к. поддержка eclipse под андроид прекращена.